# Model Data is not getting transferred to the jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have designed a Login page using Spring MVC,JPA(Hibernate) and Jsp.

Please find the login.jsp :-

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <body>
        <h2>Login page</h2>
        <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginBean" action="showProfile">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>UserName :<form:input path="userName"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Organization Id :<form:input path="OrgId" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password : <form:input path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

profilePage.jsp:-

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="staff" items="${staffData}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${staff.userName}</td>
                    <td>${staff.password}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

LoginController.java:-

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginBean", new LoginBean());
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView redirectToprofile(@ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean) {
        StaffServiceImpl staffServiceImpl = new StaffServiceImpl();
        Staff staff = staffServiceImpl.authenticateStaff(loginBean);
        if (null != staff) {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/profilePage","staffData",staff);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("profileNotFound");
        }
@RequestMapping(value = "/profilePage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showProfilePage() { 
        return "profilePage";
    }
```

After giving the valid details in the Login.jsp page it is redirecting to profilePage.jsp but the data in profilePage.jsp is not correct. Please help me to understand where i am doing the mistake.

The profilePage.jsp is displayed a below:-

UserName    Password
${staff.userName}   ${staff.password}

The Value of this variable is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

profilePage.jsp  : Add `isELIgnored="false"` in page directive.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
```

Update your controller with the following :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loginBean", new LoginBean());
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String redirectToprofile(@ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean , Model model) {
        StaffServiceImpl staffServiceImpl = new StaffServiceImpl();
        Staff staff = staffServiceImpl.authenticateStaff(loginBean);
        if (null != staff) {
           model.addAttribute("staffData",staff);
           return "profilePage";
        }
        return "profileNotFound";
    }
```

Comment: This is not working . It is just displaying UserName  Password

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is correct, and this is an explination:
The isELIgnored attribute gives you the ability to disable the evaluation of Expression Language (EL) expressions which has been introduced in JSP 2.0.

The default value of the attribute is true, meaning that expressions, ${...}, are evaluated as dictated by the JSP specification. If the attribute is set to false, then expressions are not evaluated but rather treated as static text.
Source :[enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-iselignored-attribute-in-jsp#:%7E:text=The%20isELIgnored%20attribute%20gives%20you,dictated%20by%20the%20JSP%20specification.)